# Async task getting value off of JSON return, XAML/WPF app

Tags: c#, xaml, async-await, stripe-payments

I am trying to get a single value off of a JSON return.

My call is doing an `HttpClient` call to a webservice, it returns me my Json object. I need to now get a value off of the Json return in my class so I can pass it to another method in my class as a parameter.

Current code:

```
var url = "https://localhost:9999/create_payment_intent";
var terminalAmount = new PaymentIntentCreateRequest();
terminalAmount.Amount = "2300";

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(terminalAmount);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data); //The resulting response

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var paymentIntentResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(paymentIntentResponse.ToString());
        //jsonObject returns some values {"id": "pi_xxxxxxxxx", some other data.....}
        //  PaymentIntentId = jsonObject.Id;  // I NEED THE ID VALUE OFF OF THE JSON OBJECT

        //PaymentIntentId = result.Id;
        //Call next function if result has an ID if not jump out and try again or return error
    }

    //Successful payment intent ready?
    //pass the payment intent amount to the variable

    //await response;
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are deserializing the json to a generic .NET object that does not have an Id field. It looks like a common pattern for this would be to define your own Response object that does have an Id field and deserialize your response to that https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Comment: Alternately, you can deserialize your response to a Dictionary and query that for the Id in your response https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm

Comment: You can use [DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm). With this you don't need to create a class to specify while deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

At this line you need to deserialize to an object which has the fields for what you expect to get back from the call

```
 var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponseObject>(paymentIntentResponse.ToString());
```

example being

```
    public class PaymentResponseObject{
        public string Id {get;set;}
        // all other fields
    }
```

You can then grab the fields you want from it.